# couldn't open interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces when running ifup wlan0

Tags: networking, wireless, server

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid myssidhere
    wpa-psk mypasshere
```

Output of `iwconfig`:

```
wlp5s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

**Output of iwlist scan:**
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp0s31f6  Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp5s0    Failed to read scan data : Network is down

enp4s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

Output of `ls -al /etc/network/interfaces`:

```
$ ls -al /etc/network/interfaces
-rw------- 1 root root 366 Nov  3 17:24 /etc/network/interfaces
```

**Error:**

```
~$ sudo ifdown wlp5s0 && sudo ifup -v wlp5s0
RTNETLINK answers: No such process
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlp5s0/24:ec:99:59:5d:8a
Sending on   LPF/wlp5s0/24:ec:99:59:5d:8a
Sending on   Socket/fallback
Configuring interface wlp5s0=wlp5s0 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
wpa_supplicant: wpa-driver nl80211,wext (default)
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /run/wpa_supplicant.wlp5s0.pid -i wlp5s0 -D nl80211,wext -C /run/wpa_supplicant
Starting /sbin/wpa_supplicant...
wpa_supplicant: creating sendsigs omission pidfile: /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.wpa_supplicant.wlp5s0.pid
wpa_supplicant: ctrl_interface socket located at /run/wpa_supplicant/wlp5s0
wpa_supplicant: configuring network block -- 0
wpa_supplicant: wpa-ssid "TB9JT" -- OK
wpa_supplicant: wpa-psk ***** -- OK
wpa_supplicant: enabling network block 0 -- OK

/sbin/dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.wlp5s0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.wlp5s0.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.wlp5s0.leases wlp5s0  
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
Listening on LPF/wlp5s0/24:ec:99:59:5d:8a
Sending on   LPF/wlp5s0/24:ec:99:59:5d:8a
Sending on   Socket/fallback
```

**SPECS**

```
MOTHERBOARD: ASRock H170M LGA 1151 USB 3.0 Mini ITX 
CPU: Intel Core i5-6600 6M Skylake Quad-Core 3.3 GHz LGA 1151
RAM: Crucial 8GB 288-Pin DDR4 SDRAM DDR4 2133
GPU: VGA GeForce GTX 750 2GB GDDR5 PCIe
HDD: SAMSUNG 850 EVO 2.5" 250GB SATA3 SSD
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please add the result of: `iwconfig` and also: `ls -al /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: See above please

Comment: @chili555 - any idea? i still havent gotten this fixed.

Comment: Do you have a (perhaps faulty) file? `cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: @chili555- i tried to cat the wpa_supplicant.conf and there is no file or directory...thoughts on how to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, your interface is not wlan0; it is wlp5s0. Please amend your file to read:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlp5s0
iface wlp5s0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid myssidhere
    wpa-psk mypasshere
```

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown wlp5s0 && sudo ifup -v wlp5s0
```

Check:

```
ping -c3 www.google.com
```

You may need to correct the permissions of the file:

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/network/interfaces
```

Check again:

```
sudo ifdown wlp5s0 && sudo ifup -v wlp5s0
```

Comment: I changed the config. But see the error Im getting when I try to restart the interface above please. Thoughts?

Comment: any  thoughts here?

Comment: Please see a small edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: i tried this. see the error im getting above. Anything you would suggest to fix this?

Comment: i also included an up-to-date output of iwconfig. thoughts?

Comment: also see the output of iwconfig above too

Comment: This: "Operation not possible due to RF-kill" means that the wireless switch or key combination is set to disable wireless. Please find it and switch it.

Comment: do you know where to find it? does 'rfkill unblock all' do this?

Comment: `rfkill unblock all` will not move a physical switch. What brand and model computer is it?

Comment: Its a custom PC, running ubuntu 16.04 . Ill include specs in my question. Thoughts on what to do now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48002/discussion-between-chili555-and-user700070).